# RemoveRange deletes more rows than filtered

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to delete certain rows from a table with EF.
I am using this peace of code:

MyTable is not containing PrimaryKey.

I am running this code:

```
db.MyTable.RemoveRange(db.MyTable.Where(x => x.BooleanProperty));
```

which deletes almost all the rows in MyTable.

When i use

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE BooleanProperty=1")
```

Why does `RemoveRange` does not function the way the `SqlCommand` way? (I know that the second way is more efficient, but still expecting them to function the same).

Comment: Not related to this question but why does your table not have a primary key? Does it at least have a clustered index?

Comment: How many records return this query: `db.MyTable.Where(x => x.BooleanProperty).ToList()`. All records or only the expected?

Comment: Please add some sample data and explain which posts are removed that shouldn't be removed.

Comment: @SeanLange perhaps related.  EF will issue the DELETE based on the Entity Key Properties.  If the Entity Properties aren't actually unique, the DELETE could affect additional rows.

Comment: @skipper
The same records as i would expect to be deleted.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft But `db.MyTable.Where(x => x.BooleanProperty).ToList()` returns the same records as expected to be deleted,

Comment: But EF will delete using the Entity Key for those rows.  And if the Entity Key isn’t unique in the database more rows could be deleted than were selected.